# Vanilla JavaScript function to find DOM elements given a CSS selector

Tags: javascript, html, regex, dom

I need to write a function that takes a CSS Selector as a parameter and returns an array of DOM elements matching this selector. I have to follow some rules.

- I cannot use any JS libraries.
- I cannot use querySelector/querySelectorAll.

I have a variety of test CSS selectors that I need to test my function. I think I can pass the easy ones where they're either a single tag name, class name or ID name. Then I can just do some if/else statements and call either document.getElementsByTag/Class/ID etc to get the elements.

```
function answer (selector) {
    if (selector.indexOf(".") >= 0)
        return document.getElementsByClassName(selector)
    else if (selector.indexOf("#") >= 0)
        return document.getElementById(selector)
    else 
        return document.getElementsByTagName(selector)
}
```

My problem is now if there are multiple selectors in a single query. Eg i am not sure how to handle the selector `$div.a_class#an_id`. My thinking was to split() the string at each . or # and then chain search the document for each selector one by one, but it appears you can't do that. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What CSS features do you need to support?  The CSS-selectors spec is 95 pages long.  There's a lot of esoteric stuff in there - e.g. Pseudo-classes, Child combinators, Attributes, Logical combinations, and so on.  But... you could take a peek at the source for https://sizzlejs.com/ to see what they're doing

Answer (score 2):

One option is to recursively search through the document's `.children`, and check whether the element being iterated element `.matches` the selector. If it does, push it to an array:

```js
const find = (selector, parent=document, arr=[]) => {
  [...parent.children].forEach((child) => {
    if (child.matches(selector)) {
      arr.push(child);
    }
    find(selector, child, arr);
  });
  return arr;
};

console.log(find('div.a_class#an_id'));
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="a_class" id="an_id">target!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function $(selector) {
  var element = [];
  for (let select of document.body.children) {
    if (select.matches(selector)) {
      element.push(select);
    }
  }
  return element;
}
```